# How to implement master/detail in Flutter?

Tags: flutter

I am quite new to Flutter, I have been testing it just to see what it's like and I have a pretty basic question. How do I recognize a tap on a ListView item so that I can show a detail screen?

I know the basics of the ListView, but I can't seem to find how to attach a callback for whenever an item is tapped.

What I have so far is the following:

```
    class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new MaterialApp(
          title: "Test app",
          home: new HomeScreen()
        );
      }
    }

    class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
      @override
      State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
        return new HomeState();
      }
    }

    class HomeState extends State {

      List<Item> _items;

      HomeState () {
        _items = [new Item("Item 1"), new Item("Item 2")];
      }

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {

        return new Scaffold(
          appBar: new AppBar(
              title: new Text("Test App")
          ),
          body: new Container(
              child: new ListView.builder(
                padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
                itemCount: _items.length,
                itemBuilder: (_, int index) => _items[index],
              )

          )
        );
      }

      void _onDetail(Item item) {
        print("ITEM TAPPED");
      }
    }

    class Item extends StatelessWidget {
      final String text;

      Item(this.text);

      @override
      Widget build(BuildContext context) {
        return new Container(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          child: new Center(
              child: new Text(this.text)
          )
        );
      }
    }
```

Being more specific, what do I need to do for my "onDetail" method to be called with the item that was tapped?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

[`GestureDetector`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/widgets/GestureDetector-class.html) is your friend. Or alternatively, [`InkWell`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkWell-class.html) and [`InkResponse`](https://docs.flutter.io/flutter/material/InkResponse-class.html) if you're using Material design.

Simply wrap a widget in one of these widgets, and add an `onTap` callback

Answer (score 2):

The solution, as @Darky said is to wrap each of your widgets in a GestureDetector. The solution would be:

```
class TestApp extends StatelessWidget {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(title: "Test app", home: new HomeScreen());
  }
}

class HomeScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  State<StatefulWidget> createState() {
    return new HomeState();
  }
}

class HomeState extends State {
  List<String> _items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3"];

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text("Test App")),
      body: new Container(
        child: new ListView.builder(
          padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
          itemCount: _items.length,
          itemBuilder: (_, int index) {
            var item = _items[index];
            return new GestureDetector(
              onTap: () => _onDetail(item),
              child: new Item(item),
            );
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _onDetail(String item) {
    print("ITEM TAPPED: $item");
  }
}

class Item extends StatelessWidget {
  final String text;

  Item(this.text);

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Container(
      padding: new EdgeInsets.all(8.0),
      child: new Center(
        child: new Text(this.text),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

On thing that you sould keep in mind is that you don't need to keep a refrence to a widget, just keep a refrence to the data that will be displaid in it. In your case keep a list of Strings and not of Items.